# How can I fix the issues with updating a table within my GUI?

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, bioinformatics, pysimplegui

I have an inner and outer function that work in tandem to both display and manipulate .csv files. They are both part of the greater GUI that I am creating. The the csvwindow function takes an uploaded .csv and displays it for the user. There is a button on this window, 'Calculate Diplotype', that when pressed, manipulates the data according the the diplotypecalc function, and then updates the csv window with the new dataset. The issue is... one of these functions is not working correctly. It returns an empty csv table, and none of the new column headers. Does anyone see in my code why this may be?

Below is the csvwindow function with the inner diplotypecalc function. I've tried some different ways of updating the diplotype calculator, but to no avail. I will also add my import list for ease of use.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import webview
import pandas as pd
import csv
import os
import operator

def csv_window(file_path):
    data, header_list = read_csv_file(file_path)

    sg.popup_quick_message('Building your main window.... one moment....', background_color='#1c1e23', text_color='white', keep_on_top=True, font='_ 30')

# Diplotype Calculator Functions
    def diplotype_calc(file_path):
        allele_cols = ['sample ID', 'CYP2D6', 'CYP2C9']
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, skiprows=10, usecols=allele_cols)
        allele_df = df

        # Import CPIC dataframe from Google Cloud Storage into pandas dataframe
        # Currently only supported for CYP2D6 and CYP2C9
        cpic_data = f'https://storage.googleapis.com/pg-genotyping-cpic-2d6-2d9/2d6_2d9_joined.csv'
        cpic_df = pd.read_csv(cpic_data)

        # Merge the two DataFrames based on the common columns CYP2D6 and CYP2C9
        merged_df = pd.merge(allele_df, cpic_df, on=['CYP2D6', 'CYP2C9'])

        # Create two new columns to store the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score
        merged_df['Metabolizer Status'] = ''
        merged_df['Activity Score'] = ''

        # Create two dictionaries to store the metabolizer status and activity score for each call
        d6_status_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2D6'], cpic_df['Metabolizer Status']))
        d9_status_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2C9'], cpic_df['Metabolizer Status']))
        d6_activity_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2D6'], cpic_df['Activity Score']))
        d9_activity_dict = dict(zip(cpic_df['CYP2C9'], cpic_df['Activity Score']))

        # Create two new columns to store the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score
        allele_df['Metabolizer Status'] = ''
        allele_df['Activity Score'] = ''

        # Iterate over each row of the allele DataFrame
        for index, row in allele_df.iterrows():
            # Get the cyp2d6 and cyp2c9 calls for the current sample ID
            cyp2d6_call = row['CYP2D6']
            cyp2c9_call = row['CYP2C9']

            # Use the dictionaries to get the metabolizer status and activity score for the current calls
            cyp2d6_status = d6_status_dict.get(cyp2d6_call, 'UND')
            cyp2c9_status = d9_status_dict.get(cyp2c9_call, 'UND')
            cyp2d6_activity = d6_activity_dict.get(cyp2d6_call, 'UND')
            cyp2c9_activity = d9_activity_dict.get(cyp2c9_call, 'UND')

            # Use the comparison results to populate the Metabolizer Status and Activity Score columns of the allele DataFrame
            allele_df.loc[index, 'Metabolizer Status'] = f'2D6: {cyp2d6_status} ||| 2C9: {cyp2c9_status}'
            allele_df.loc[index, 'Activity Score'] = f'{cyp2d6_activity}, {cyp2c9_activity}'

        # Export the modified DataFrame to a new CSV file
        allele_df.to_csv('modified_dataframe.csv', index=False)

        # Here we update the table with the modified csv file from the diplotype
        # Here we update the table with the modified csv file from the diplotype_calc function
        window['-TABLE-'].update(values=pd.read_csv('modified_dataframe.csv').values.tolist())



    # ------ Window Layout ------
    layout = [  [sg.Text('Click a heading to sort on that column or enter a filter and click a heading to search for matches in that column')],
                [sg.Text(f'{len(data)} Records in table', font='_ 18')],
                [sg.Text(k='-RECORDS SHOWN-', font='_ 18')],
                [sg.Text(k='-SELECTED-')],
                [sg.T('Filter:'), sg.Input(k='-FILTER-', focus=True, tooltip='Not case sensative\nEnter value and click on a col header'),
                 sg.B('Reset Table', tooltip='Resets entire table to your original data'), sg.Button('Calculate Diplotype', key='-DIPLO-'),
                 sg.Checkbox('Sort Descending', k='-DESCENDING-'), sg.Checkbox('Filter Out (exclude)', k='-FILTER OUT-', tooltip='Check to remove matching entries when filtering a column'),
                 sg.Push()],
                [sg.Table(values=data, headings=header_list, max_col_width=25,
                        auto_size_columns=True, display_row_numbers=True, vertical_scroll_only=True,
                        justification='right', num_rows=50,
                        key='-TABLE-', selected_row_colors='red on yellow', enable_events=True,
                        expand_x=True, expand_y=True,
                        enable_click_events=True)],
                [sg.Sizegrip()]]

    # ------ Create Window ------
    window = sg.Window('CSV Table Display', layout, right_click_menu=sg.MENU_RIGHT_CLICK_EDITME_VER_EXIT,  resizable=True, size=(900, 600), finalize=True)
    window.bind("<Control_L><End>", '-CONTROL END-')
    window.bind("<End>", '-CONTROL END-')
    window.bind("<Control_L><Home>", '-CONTROL HOME-')
    window.bind("<Home>", '-CONTROL HOME-')
    original_data = data        # save a copy of the data
    # ------ Event Loop ------
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        # print(event, values)
        if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
            break
        if values['-TABLE-']:           # Show how many rows are slected
            window['-SELECTED-'].update(f'{len(values["-TABLE-"])} rows selected')
        else:
            window['-SELECTED-'].update('')
        if event[0] == '-TABLE-':
        # if is instance(event, tuple):
            filter_value = values['-FILTER-']
            # TABLE CLICKED Event has value in format ('-TABLE=', '+CLICKED+', (row,col))
            if event[0] == '-TABLE-':
                if event[2][0] == -1 and event[2][1] != -1:  # Header was clicked and wasn't the "row" column
                    col_num_clicked = event[2][1]
                    # if there's a filter, first filter based on the column clicked
                    if filter_value not in (None, ''):
                        filter_out = values['-FILTER OUT-']     # get bool filter out setting
                        new_data = []
                        for line in data:
                            if not filter_out and (filter_value.lower() in line[col_num_clicked].lower()):
                                new_data.append(line)
                            elif filter_out and (filter_value.lower() not in line[col_num_clicked].lower()):
                                new_data.append(line)
                        data = new_data
                    new_table = sort_table(data, (col_num_clicked, 0), values['-DESCENDING-'])
                    window['-TABLE-'].update(new_table)
                    data = new_table
                    window['-RECORDS SHOWN-'].update(f'{len(new_table)} Records shown')
                    window['-FILTER-'].update('')           # once used, clear the filter
                    window['-FILTER OUT-'].update(False)  # Also clear the filter out flag
        elif event == 'Reset Table':
            data = original_data
            window['-TABLE-'].update(data)
            window['-RECORDS SHOWN-'].update(f'{len(data)} Records shown')
        elif event == '-DIPLO-' or event == 'calculate':
            diplotype_calc(file_path)
            data, header_list = read_csv_file('modified_dataframe.csv')
            window['-TABLE-'].update(data)
            window['-RECORDS SHOWN-'].update(f'{len(data)} Records Shown')
        elif event == '-CONTROL END-':
            window['-TABLE-'].set_vscroll_position(100)
        elif event == '-CONTROL HOME-':
            window['-TABLE-'].set_vscroll_position(0)
        elif event == 'Edit Me':
            sg.execute_editor(__file__)
        elif event == 'Version':
            sg.popup_scrolled(__file__, sg.get_versions(), location=window.current_location(), keep_on_top=True, non_blocking=True)
    window.close()
```

Comment: I'd really encourage you to break this problem down some.  You've got 140 lines of densely packed code and it's going to be difficult for someone who's not familiar with it to help you.  Add some debugging to the code to validate that the values are what you think and break the code into smaller pieces.  Let us know if you get stuck.